# getIntent() with Firestore Cloud Messaging not showing the Key Value Data

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I've created an `Android` App that will have some daily news, and when any urgent news is published I will manually send a notification from `FCM` and when a user clicks on it, then the user will be redirected to my desired activity.

Here is the code on:

### Main Activity to find the Key-Value data:

```
if(getIntent()!=null && getIntent().hasExtra("key1")){

        for(String key: getIntent().getExtras().keySet()){

            Toast.makeText(this, "The key received: "+getIntent().getExtras().getString(key), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }
```

And code for:

### FirebaseMessagingService

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
    }

    public void showNotification(String title, String message){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"MyNotifications").
                setContentTitle(title).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon).setAutoCancel(true).setContentText(message);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(999,builder.build());
    }


    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
    }
}
```

And here goes my:

### Manifest.xml

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

If a tell, in short, I don't see the Toast, if I get the Toast, I can redirect the user based on the Key-Value Data.